# Find Redirect URL from Html source in javascript or c#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, redirect

I try to check html of some sites, but there is redirect on content.
How could to get redirected URL from html?

Note: With these code, we are able to redirect the page:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.href = "http://example.com"
</script>
```

or

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/product.php?item=swedish-fish"/>
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="3; url=http://example.com/alternate_url.html">
```

or

```
<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3" />
</noscript>
```

....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `id` attribute to the meta tag, like so:

`<meta id="idRefresh" http-equiv="Refresh" content="5555555; url=http://example.com/alternate_url.html"/>`

Then use straight Javascript

```
var e = document.querySelector("meta[id='idRefresh']");
var content = e && e.getAttribute("content");
var result = content && content.replace("5555555; url=","");

console.log(result);
//results in
//http://example.com/alternate_url.html
```

NOTE: If you change the refresh time (5555555 in my test example) then you will also need to change it in the `replace(..)` method

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this isn't works for <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="3; url=http://example.com/alternate_url.html"> or for window.location.href = "http://example.com".

Comment: @مهدینبوی try a lowercase r in Refresh.  i.e. `http-equiv="refresh"` and be sure you are referencing the `JQuery` library before this code.  EDIT: I edited the code in the answer to be case-insensitive with the `i` flag if you would like to try it

Comment: @مهدینبوی I could not get my previous answer to work properly.  The edited one now should.